# Context in android

Tags: java, android

i am a newbie.Please explain what all things are passed through a context.Like when constructing an object for the following class..

public class myclass{

public myclass (Context context){....}
}

Comment: Found source code at http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/content/Context.java.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a lot of possibilities to check for or change System or application properties.
You will find a detailed version of all the functions that are available with the context in the api documentation of android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

So you will be able for example to start a service (to run part of the application in the background) through context.startService(Intent service). You'll need to pass an Intent (if you don't know what an intent is I would read the  Dev Guide: http:**developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html first. You could do that anyway, there are plenty of good descriptions and examples.).

Sorry for the crippled link, I'm not allowed to post more than one link per post...

Comment: Thank you. But i hope it will take time for me to get an overall view. :D